# Use an enhanced editor like TinyMCE while editing page in Composite C1

Tags: c1-cms

Is it possible to override the basic editor for editing pages in Composite C1 and use an enhanced Text editor like TinyMCE in its place?
Please suggest the steps involved in implementing it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Composite C1 is using TinyMCE already. The toolbar have been servery simplified and adapted to Composite C1 features (like media archive, internal linking and C1 Function access) but the core is a fairly up to date TinyMCE.

There is a way to customize the toolbar, described here: http://docs.composite.net/Console/CustomizingVisualEditor

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I Would like to add Font Names, Size and a Font-color toolbox similar to that present in Microsoft Word. If you could suggest the steps involved. Is there a plugin available for these toolboxes and how can i use them in the XML file. Thanks.

Comment: The Visual Editor in Composite C1 centers around CSS classes - it actively promotes the use of css instead of having style information embedded inside the content html. Instead of giving end-users the ability to chose any font or color, front-end developers are expected to deliver the styling matching the website. Beside from ensuring that the website stays visually "tight" and within design guidelines, this also ensures content can be redesigned easily. On http://docs.composite.net/Console/CustomizingVisualEditor/StyleSelector you can read about adding a style.

Comment: I agree with mawtex - you shouldn't really add font names and sizes in by hand. If you then want to change it later you'd have to change every single one by hand on every page (without even having a way to search for them). Just let users pick from the list of CSS styles and then customise the styles as you see fit or you'll dig yourself into a big hole :)